# How to synchronize WSO2 Secondary User Store with AD?

Tags: wso2

We are planning use WSO2 with multitenant.
We have an Active Directory with users where the AD's group name contains the role name and the client domain ("publisher_domain")
Each tenant will have a separate secondary User Store, so users from the one User Store will belong to the one tenant.
We are going to synchronize users and roles from AD with Secondary User Store (will define the User Store by the tenant domain as part of the name of the AD group).

How should we set up synchronization between AD and User Stores?

Custom User Store Management - is it correct way?

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronize users and roles from AD with Secondary User Store"?

Comment: I mean import users from AD to one of the Secondary User Store (tenant) according user's AD group and set roles using mapping AD roles on wso roles. If later new user is added to AD, he will be imported to the UserStore, If user is removed from AD group- he will be removed from the UserStore  in sync period

Comment: That doesn't sound correct. Why do you want to duplicate data? Just connect the AD with the correct user filter to each tenant.

Comment: In AD i have one user (UserA@xxx.com) under 2 groups (role1_tenant1, role2_tenant2).

Comment: In AD i have one user (UserA@xxx.com) under 2 groups (role1_tenant1, role2_tenant2). In wso2 should be created 2 tenants - Tenant1, Tenant2. In UserStore under Tenant1 should be created UserA@tenant1.com with wso2 role as result of mapping role1 to wso role. In UserStore under Tenant2 should be created UserA@tenant2.com. If user logins as UserA@tenant1.com- he will work in Tenant1, if logins as UserA@tenant2.com- he will work in Tenant2